# Can't click top half of bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a basic `btn-block btn-sm` button in bootstrap that is at a fixed position using `position:sticky; top:10px` in my CSS. The problem is, the button doesn't show any hover effects, and you can't click on it, when the cursor is on the top half of the button. In addition, for a little but below the button, you can hover over it and the button shows hover effects, and when you click on it, a button `click` event is registered. It looks like the "clickable" portion of the button is offset by about 10px.

My other button(the Send button) doesn't seem to have this issue, so it looks like it has to do with the `position sticky` styling for that button.

Nobody else seems to have asked any questions similar to this, so I  don't really even know how to get started with trying to find a solution.

**Some of my code:**

```css
#latest-msg {
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card" id="chat-wrapper">
    <div class="card-header text-left" id="chat-title">
        Chat
    </div>
    <div class="card-body" id="chat-messages">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm" id="latest-msg">Latest Message</button>
        <!--^^^THIS BUTTON-->

        <p id="no-msg" class="text-muted">No Messages Yet. Be the first!</p>
        <!--Some text is appended here via javascript.-->
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted text-right hidden " id="footer-send">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Message..." id="name">

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="name-enter">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted text-right" id="footer-name">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message..." id="chat-msg-box"></textarea>

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="msg-send">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When running your code in code snippet it appears to be working. How are you referencing bootstrap and what version?

Comment: 4.0.0-beta3. I know it's beta, but my other button works fine, so i'm worried it might be a issue on my side.

Comment: i have edited the question, since it is using bootstrap 4. So i edited it to beta 3. But it seems working even though there are small front end changes. Maybe some other style overriding your bootstrap. Check the related attributes

Comment: You can see it on https://techeditbeta.jeffkmeng.com/404.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to a javascript file shows that the button does get clicked.

You can also check it out here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bazLvp

```js
document.getElementById('latest-msg').addEventListener('click', buttonClicked);

function buttonClicked() {
  console.log('the button was clicked');
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that it doesn't register as "clicking" on the button. I am using a event listener right now, but it only registers when I click towards the bottom of the button(and even a little below the button)